# Connectivity and the triangle inequality

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

It is well known that if a weight function of a graph satisfies the triangle inequality, then 2 vertex connectivity is same as 2 edge connectivity in that graph. Can someone find a proof for this?

I looked at many papers, but couldn't find anything clear about the proof.

Comment: @Yikai Normally the weight function would be the distance between two nodes. Let $u,v$ and $w$ be three nodes, then the triangle inequality for the weight function will be $d(u,v)<=d(u,w)+d(w,v)$. A graph is connected if for any two vertices $x, y ∈ V (G)$, there is a path whose endpoints are $x$ and $y$. A connected graph G is called 2-connected if for every vertex $x ∈ V (G), G − x$ is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connectivity and triangle inequality for distance function don't have anything common. There is a graph $G = \overline{\overline{2K_2}\cup K_1}$ that is 2-edge-conncted but is not 2-vertex-connected. You may use any distance function for it.

So, $G = (\{\,1, 2, 3, 4, 5\,\}, \{\,\{\,1, 2\,\}, \{\,3, 4\,\}, \{\,1, 5\,\}, \{\,2, 5\,\}, \{\,3, 5\,\}, \{\,4, 5\,\}\,\})$. Let $d(u, v) = A_{uv}$ for
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Probably it was meant that 2-vertex-connected graph is 2-edge-connected. That is true since $\kappa(G) \le \lambda(G)$ for any graph $G$, and this faact has no relation to distance function.